Clicking a button to populate a div with value, and then use this value for an onclick function - Javascript
I have a text box here which when I click into it and press a letter, it populates with that letter. Then I click a button (Go) which takes the letter I have entered and runs a JavaScript function that works. This is the code:
<div id="enterlettertext">
  Enter the letter:&nbsp;
  <input type="text" id="myletterInput" name="myletterInput" />
</div>
<input type="button" id="wadgo" value="Go" 
   onclick="QuizAnswer(document.getElementById('myletterInput').value)">

Rather than clicking into the text box to enter a letter, I want to build an onscreen keyboard where the user presses the button representing the letter and this letter populates the text box. The user would then click 'Go' to run the function.
I built the following as the keyboard:
<button class="fiveninebutton" onclick="setLetter('q');">Q</button>
<button class="fiveninebutton" onclick="setLetter('w');">W</button>
<button class="fiveninebutton" onclick="setLetter('e');">E</button>
<button class="fiveninebutton" onclick="setLetter('r');">R</button>

And have this code:
function setLetter(letter) {
  document.getElementById('myletterInput').innerHTML =    
  document.getElementById('myletterInput').innerHTML + letter;
}

When I click the letter button, nothing happens.  However, if I change:
<input type="text" id="myletterInput" name="myletterInput" /> 

to:
<div id="myletterInput" name="myletterInput"></div>

the letter is populated in the div just as I want it to - but the 'go' button function no longer works.
How do I get the letter to populate the div and then the other function which uses this button to work?

Input elements need a value, not innerHTML 

document.getElementById('myletterInput').value += letter;

There is a difference between innerHTML and value.
InnerHTML is often HTML code.
<div></div>can contain HTML code in the middle, so using innerHTML on the div is correct.
In input, if you want to assign something to the text of input, you should use the value of input.
How to fix:
Choose one of the following two situations.
If you use div, innerHTML is fine, but you need to change the value in the Go button to innerHTML as well, otherwise as you said, it won't take effect.
If you use input, the value in the Go button is correct. You need to change all innerHTML in the function setLetter to value.

Thank you @heygsc! I managed to get everything to work by using the input option. However, I can't get the div version to work.

@BarryG
In the case of div, in your problem description, the modified div and innerHTML in the function setLetter are correct, just change the value in the go button to innerHTML.
I tried it and it works fine. We cannot see the content of the QuizAnswer function. If the logic here is correct, there should be no problem.
Perhaps you could check the details above, or put the code here for further analysis?
